# Uipath data scraping error - cannot find the UI Element corresponding to this selector

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I use UiPath and `data scraping` activity. First open the browser direct to the e-commerce site and search the product. Everything is fine, until after the product was searched and results were shown, the output gives the following error message:

> Cannot find the UI Element corresponding to this selector

I deleted the data scraping activity from my project and create a new and exactly same data scraping activity again and it works without error. However, when I close the UiPath project and open it again, the error start showing again when I run it. Why does that happen?

[image: Image of the error output]

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, do not forget to upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am sorry, my stackoverflow reputation is less than 15, therefore it is unable to publicly display the upvote.

Comment: I see. Maybe come back in some month when you have more. Also make sure to check out the UiPath Academy. This is free and you learn things like I taught you here. Things like handling the selector are some basics you need to know. Wish you all the best with your project.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thank you kwoxer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious reason is that the **selector** is **changing** every time you visit it. So first you need to analyze your issue:

- compare the exact error messages
- those will differ by the `refer_pv_id`
- this id is generated on every new visit obviously
- so every time you visit the page you are getting a new one that is not matching with the old one

To fix this you need to change your selector and using wildcards. So for your example this will be:

`...home&amp;refer_pv_id=*' title=...`